# Java JDK VScode issues

Tags: java, openjdk-11, sdkman

I installed java jdk using sdkman on my windows machine. I am using wsl for this purpose.

[image]

However, I need to add this to my VScode and when I look at the installed jdk's available to me I only see these:

[image]

This does not display the JDK I installed using sdkman which is located in the folder `\\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\devt\.sdkman\candidates\java`. I do not know how to direct my `JAVA_HOME` variable to this location.

Comment: Why would you want to use a Linux JDK on windows?

Comment: our professor said we should use sdkman to download java 11 and I did it using wsl.

Comment: i am very confused about that part and if i messed up

Comment: Could it be he meant you should use sdkman only if you are using Linux?

Comment: is it possible to run sdkman on the windows command prompt?

Comment: You will probably not be able to create a user interface and also run into other difficulties when using a Linux JDK under windows. Just install the windows version of whatever JDK he told you to install and use that one in VSCode.

Comment: i mean I googled it and it said we need WSL..however when I downloaded sdkman and the JDK using sdkman, it gets placed in this \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\devt\.sdkman\candidates\java which is not accessible when i try to set the path or something

Comment: Just install a windows version of the JDK. Using sdkman on windows will probably give you nothing but trouble.

Comment: thats exactly what I am experiencing... TROUBLEE!!

Comment: Add the sdkman path to java.home in vscode settings.json

Comment: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Answer (score 0):

They now provide a complete extension for connection to wsl. WSL is a separate user-space inside NT kernel. Your VS-Code is running in windows userspace. Hard way to do it would be to remote into your wsl, and configure there. Easy way would be to install vscode inside wsl, because windows now let you install and use linux GUI apps via wsl. Or use the extension they provide, which works on the microsoft build of vscode,( It doesn't work with non-microsoft binaries of vscode, like code-oss, vscodium etc.)

Complete instructions on working with WSL is documented here.
https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/wsl

Answer (score 0):

first step

(- Install java jdk first

- open settings in vs code
- search for "jdk" in settings
- In java Home
- paste the jdk path:- C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-20\bin
  )

2nd Step
(

- open settings in vs code
- search for "jdk" in settings
- In java Home - settings json -(Open it)
  and add

"java.home":"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_161"

)

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19182-01/821-0917/inst_jdk_javahome_t/index.html

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).